# "aaaa".StartsWith("aaa") returns false

Tags: c#, string, startswith

If this is not a bug, can anyone then explain the reason behind this behavior? Indeed it seems that every odd number of letters will return false:

```
string test = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aa"));
Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaa"));
Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaa"));
Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaaa"));
Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaaaa"));
Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaaaaa"));
```

yields following output when executed on a Danish system:

```
True
False
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: I don't believe it can be true. For example, in Ideone, [not](http://ideone.com/F3S7vQ) Can be a `Culture` thing maybe..

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code snippet to LINQPad - every line gave `true`.

Comment: How are you doing this? I copied your code and it yields all 'True'.

Comment: This question is not so bad. Not everyone have the same culture!

Comment: @Matthew Well surely you agree that the culture is a pretty crucial information here, and even with an appropriate culture, Mono does *not* reproduce this behaviour. But yeah, that was a bummer.

Comment: Matthew is right, I found it out myself right after I posted the question. In danish aa corresponds to "å" so that's why every odd number of a's returns false. Comparing by invariant culture fixes the problem :)

Comment: Just another `Culture` issue.. http://ideone.com/vHT1rR

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment of earlier - yes, the culture is pretty important info BUT it would have been a good idea to ask about it before downvoting! The OP might not have thought about it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is certainly due to your current culture.
You may be in Danish in which aa is considered a letter.
If you try changing the culture.. or the case, it shall work.

I think I remember similar behaviour with hungarian cultures and letter associations

Have a look to [String StartsWith() issue with Danish text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535910/string-startwith-issue-with-danish-text)

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
            string test = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aa"));
            Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaa"));
            Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaa"));
            Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaaa"));
            Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaaaa"));
            Console.WriteLine(test.StartsWith("aaaaaaa"));
        }
    }
}
```

This prints what the OP claims.

Comment: Executing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-hu");` before his code still results in all lines yielding `True`.

Comment: My appologies.. It is danish. Try and set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK");

Comment: But indeed, danish yields the expected - or rather *unexpected* - results of the OP: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da");`

Comment: Still doesn’t work on Mono but that may be due to lacking locale support. However, can you explain more on *why* this behaviour is the way it is? I don’t understand it even though I have a passable grasp of Unicode, encoding and locales.

Comment: Indeed, in danish "aa" corresponds to the single letter "å", which is the reason every odd number of a's resulted in false. :)